# Why EIGS is not able to reproduce the same result as EIG for a generalised eigenvalue problem?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I have an generalised eigenvalue problem:

A**q = alpha**B*q

where `A` and `B` are complex square matrices.
Using `eig` I can easily find the correct answer for a given `A` and `B` matrices:

```
from scipy import linalg
alpha, q = linalg.eig(A,B)
```

And if I plot the result eigenvalues alpha in a complex plan where `alpha_r` is the real part of the eigenvalue and `alpha_i` is the imaginary part of the eigenvalue:

[image]

Now I would like to solve the same problem but using `eigs` sparse algorithms from Scipy and something weird happens:

```
from scipy.linalg.sparse import eigs
alpha, q = eigs(A,k=40,B,sigma=1.0+0.0J)
```

[image]

I know that's probably something related with the characteristics of the matrices `A` and `B` but I don't know exactly what. Using `eigs` is suppose to be more efficient specially if the matrices are sparse.

Here you can find the `A` and `B` data, `eig`solution and `eigs`solution:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p_3AZzRtFfF64P7Sh5tDEA-I-voRtfAi?usp=share_link

To load the data:

```
import numpy as np

data  = np.load('YourPath/matrix.npz')
A     = data['A']
B     = data['B']
data  = np.load('YourPath/eig_result.npz')
alpha = data['alpha']
q     = data['q']
data  = np.load('YourPath/eigs_result.npz')
alpha = data['alpha']
q     = data['q']
```

Comment: When posting data with Google Drive, please ensure that the sharing setting is set to 'anyone with the link,' or other people will not be able to access your data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and yes, the data is available for everybody.

Comment: I don't believe it is: https://i.imgur.com/kGnCBsX.png

Comment: I just updated the access

Answer (score 0):

At first, I didn't think there was anything strange here. After correcting the syntax and import errors:

```py
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs
alpha, q = eigs(A, 40, B, sigma=1 + 0j)
```

`alpha` contains `40` eigenvalues near the specified `sigma`. It's not immediately obvious from your plot, but upon closer inspection, these don't appear to be eigenvalues returned by `scipy.linalg.eig`. In fact, when I specify a different `sigma`, say `4+4j`, `alpha` is returned with `40` values near `sigma` - but these are obviously not present in your plot.

I agree that this is not desirable behavior, but it is probably because your `M` matrix (`B`) does not satisfy the requirements specified in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html).

> M: An array, sparse matrix, or LinearOperator representing the operation M@x for the generalized eigenvalue problem

> A @ x = w * M @ x.

> M must represent a real symmetric matrix if A is real, and **must represent a complex Hermitian matrix if A is complex**.

`A` is complex, but your `B` matrix is not Hermitian; all the nonzero diagonal components are `0 - 1j`.